# Google Map Integration iOS 1.9.0 issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Please provide solution on below error for google map iOS  integration, Which i am facing from last two days but not getting any solution on this.

Find the below log for reference

2014-11-27 11:38:09.230 MapPin[2279:41725] CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'GMSCachedTile' for entity 'GMSCachedTile'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
2014-11-27 11:38:09.231 MapPin[2279:41730] CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'GMSCachedObject' for entity 'GMSCachedObject'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
2014-11-27 11:38:09.233 MapPin[2279:41725] -[NSManagedObject tileCoords]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a174ac0
2014-11-27 11:38:09.235 MapPin[2279:41725] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject tileCoords]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a174ac0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x03466946 **exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x030efa97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0346e5c5 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x033b73e7 ___forwarding_** + 1047
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x033b6fae _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   MapPin                              0x0011e892 __47-[GMSTileDataCache startWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke57 + 761
    6   MapPin                              0x00123bc4 -[GMSTileDataCache fetchTilesImmediateWithPredicate:sortDescriptor:completionHandler:] + 389
    7   MapPin                              0x0011e44c __47-[GMSTileDataCache startWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 474
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0391e30a _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0393ee2f _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03924afc _dispatch_queue_drain + 1475
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x039243c3 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 212
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03927067 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 466
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0392884a _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 115
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x03c9a296 _pthread_wqthread + 724
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x03c97eea start_wqthread + 30
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 4):

If you're following this tutorial (http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift) but trying to implement this in your existing project, you probably skipped over the step to add -ObjC to the Other Linker Flags under the Build Settings for the Project.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got exactly the same error. I had to remove all libs and re-add all the following libs. Then it just worked. Still don't know the exact thing fixed my issue. Just wanted to share what I did. If you know what exactly fixed your issue, I would love to know.

(excerpted from google map sdk site):

```
AVFoundation.framework
CoreData.framework
CoreLocation.framework
CoreText.framework
GLKit.framework
ImageIO.framework
libc++.dylib
libicucore.dylib
libz.dylib
OpenGLES.framework
QuartzCore.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
```

Comment: Starting from 1.10 also add:

`Accelerate.framework,
CoreBluetooth.framework, 
CoreFoundation.framework, 
libobjc.dylib`