# How to use use_frameworks cocoa pods and Google SDK

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am building a simple iOS (Swift) application - which renders a map and plot markers on it.

It was working fine when my Podfile was

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'

pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

But when I changed it to this (notice the use_frameworks!)

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'
use_frameworks!

pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.3'
```

I am getting the following error.

Error:

```
CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'GMSCachedObject' for entity 'GMSCachedObject'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
2015-08-11 12:30:44.419 Closest[1784:15704] CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'GMSCachedTile' for entity 'GMSCachedTile'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
2015-08-11 12:30:44.421 Closest[1784:15704] -[NSManagedObject tileCoords]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff6d0cbf750
2015-08-11 12:30:44.450 Closest[1784:15704] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject tileCoords]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff6d0cbf750'
```

What should I be doing different ?

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164191/google-map-integration-ios-1-9-0-issue

Comment: This one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579875/use-frameworks-in-cocoapods-for-analytics/31602856#31602856

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and neither linked solution works for me. I'm using Xcode 7 beta 6; OP, what version of Xcode are you on?

Answer (score 2):

> After some debugging I realised that the issue arose when attempting to use both ObjectiveC pods (such as GoogleMapsSDK) and Swift libraries such as Alamofire.
>
> A really simple solution is to add -ObjC to your linkers in XCode which will tell it to compile the ObjectiveC pods.
>
> After adding the linker everything compiles and I’m able to use the two pods in unison.

Source: http://luke-berry.co.uk/2015/08/19/google-maps-and-alamofire/

Answer (score 0):

use Like this:
target 'UrAppApp' do 
pod 'SmartDeviceLink-iOS', '4.0.1'

use_frameworks! 
pod "ExpandingMenu"

end