# Google maps swift ios mapwithframe on GMSMapView error

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, callstack

I am using the Google Maps iOS SDK(using swift) and after successfully running my program multiple times I decided to exit Xcode to resume working on my project later. After re-opening Xcode and trying to relaunch my project I get this error:

> **Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject tileCoords]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c037e90'**.

It is saying that there is no mapWithFrame method on the GMSMapView object, although I copied the sample code directly off of the Google maps SDK website.

Could I receive a bit more guidance on handling this issue? Here is an image of the call stack [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Tbm.png) and the line of the code it is blowing up on.

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(37.5784623,longitude:-77.42166750000001, zoom: 4)
```

*Blows up here* ---->

```
mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing map view with frame only and in view will appear set its camera as follow:

```
mapView = GMSMapView(frame: CGRectZero)
// on view will appear
mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(37.5784623,longitude:-77.42166750000001, zoom: 4)
```

Comment: I actually got some good advice from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164191/google-map-integration-ios-1-9-0-issue